# Convert String to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a string

```
str = "Name John"
```

I want to change it to a dictionary.

```
{"Name":"John"}
```

How do I achieve this?
I Have tried using comprehension but I get an error.

```
str = "Arjun 23344"
Name = {str.split()}
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daphney/Python/AGame.py", line 2, in <module>
    Name = {x.split()}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You might want to include other examples.  Will the string always be just two parts, the key and value?  What if it's `str = "Name John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split:

```
my_dict = {str.split(" ")[0]:str.split(" ")[1]}
```

Note: If you have, say, `Name John Smith` and want the dict to be `Name:Smith`, then you can just change the `[1]` to `[-1]` to get the last indexed item.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary using `dict` function by providing list of [key,value] lists (or (key,value) tuples):

```
my_str = "Arjun 23344"
Name = dict([my_str.split()])
print(Name) # output: {'Arjun': '23344'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = dict([str.split()])
```

This would only work if your string always splits into **exactly** two words. This works because the `split` call returns a list of two elements, which is then stored inside a containing list, and passed to the `dict` constructor. The latter can work properly with a sequence (`list` or other) of pairs (`list`s or other).

This works in this particular case, but is not robust or portable.

Answer (score 0):

As there are only two strings in your variable.

```
string = "Name Shivank"
k,v = string.split()
d = dict()
d[k] = v 
print(d) #output: {'Name':'Shivank'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a second parameter to the split function to limit the number of separations (to 1 in this case):

```
dict([string.split(" ",1)])
```